# Circle in the plane becomes cylinder in space?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I understand how the equation for example, $x^2 + (y-1)^2 = 5$, describes a circle on a 2d plane; but I was told that in space (3d) the same equation describes a cylinder, and I don't understand that.

Is the idea that in 3d space there is always an implicit $z$, here of any value since not assigned one, and therefore you get a cylinder of infinite height/depth?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might help to distinguish between the equation and the set of points that satisfy it.

An equation is a string of symbols. But when you say "it describes" a circle, you're talking about the points in $\mathbb{R}^2$ that satisfy it. And it feels very natural to pair up the two concepts.

But the "points in $\mathbb{R}^2$" is a very important part of your description. The following are all very different:
$$ \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid x^2 + (y - 1)^2 = 5 \} $$
$$ \{ (x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 \mid x^2 + (y - 1)^2 = 5 \} $$
$$ \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{Q}^2 \mid x^2 + (y - 1)^2 = 5 \} $$

The first is a circle, the second is a cylinder, and the third is a speckling of points along a circle. In general, it is important to define what kind of objects you're talking about before turning equations into sets.

Comment: thanks, that makes sense; I can see how important the context is.

Answer (score 3):

The equation $x=1$ defines a point in the real line. However, if you consider it in the plane it defines a line, since $y$ has no any restriction and, thus, it can take any value.

The same happens with your question. Since $z$ has no any restriction you have a line trough any point of the circle, which gives an infinite cylinder.

Comment: thank you, that's visually pretty intuitive, which is always good for me.

Answer (score 3):

A not-so-technical explanation:

View the cylinder from bird's eye view, at an arbitrary height $z=h$ (say e.g. $z=3$, or $z=9$). No matter what value of $h$ you prescribe, the cylinder--when viewed orthogonally--will still look like a circle of radius $r$, and it takes the circle equation $x^2+y^2=r^2$, like below: 
[image]

And this circle is indeed a cylinder that's pointing up or down from the page, at some arbitrary height $z=h$.

Comment: thanks, I find that kind of visual intuition very helpful.